# How to sort the first elements of List of Lists in alphabetical order?

Tags: java, list, sorting

First of all what i would like the program to do is sort the lists by the first element of each list in alphabetical order.
And then sort them back into its original order.
Code below.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mylist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    List<String> List1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> List2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> List3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List1.add("A");
    List2.add("B");
    List3.add("A");
    List1.add("C");
    List2.add("D");
    List3.add("E"); 
    mylist.add((ArrayList<String>) List1);
    mylist.add((ArrayList<String>) List2);
    mylist.add((ArrayList<String>) List3);
    System.out.println(mylist.toString());
```

The Print at the minute is:

[[A, C], [B, D], [A, E]]

I would like to sort them so the result is like:

[[A, C], [A, E], [B, D]]

and then be able to sort them back into its original form:

[[A, C], [B, D], [A, E]]

Comment: Create a copy of the enclosing list, and sort that copy. You'll have the original list in the original order, and the copy sorted by first element. You can't "undo" a sort: sorting is not reversible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can sort the list using a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). If you are using Java 8 you can do it like this:

```
mylist.sort((l1, l2) -> l1.get(0).compareTo(l2.get(0)));
```

Note that this will modify the original list, though, and there is no way to reverse the sort. Instead, you should create a copy and sort the copy.

For example:

```
List<List<String>> listToSort = new ArrayList<>(mylist);
listToSort.sort((l1, l2) -> l1.get(0).compareTo(l2.get(0)));
System.out.println(listToSort);
```

Output:

```
[[A, C], [A, E], [B, D]]
```

Note:

If you are using Java 7 and below, you should use `Collections.sort()` and create an explicit `Comparator`.

Comment: Note lambda's were introduced in java 8, so these snippets won't compile in versions less than 8

Comment: Yes. I added a note to the answer so the OP is warned. Thanks.

Comment: The method sort((<no type> List1, <no type> List2) -> {}) is undefined for the type ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> I am getting this error in the line: 'listToSort.sort((List1, List2)->List1.get(0).compareTo(List2.get(0)));'

Comment: @TimDaiber It looks like you're using an older Java version. `List.sort()` works on Java 8. You should update to Java 8 if you can. If you can't, copeg's answer should work fine.

Comment: @Anderson Vieira I have updated to 1.8 but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @TimDaiber Are you using Eclipse? If yes, you should use a version that supports Java 8, such as [Luna](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/lunasr2). [This video](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DDnHUMHxjaxg&ei=-XcdVdClCpKYyATJ64GoCQ&usg=AFQjCNEzJIlih1lo7ND6-bYFIpKjNxmRxw&sig2=uIeU2nRBffPCvq3UYCqM9A&bvm=bv.89744112,d.aWw) shows how to configure it.

Comment: @Anderson Vieira Hello sorry for not giving any updates. I have now upgraded to 1.8 and the code above works perfect. If you could answer one question it would be great before I close this.  My question is how if the number of array list would change to 5, 6, 7 or more how would I do that? So that it is not hard coded into the code and can change depending on the number of array list. Would I need a for loop?

Comment: @TimDaiber Could you update your question with an explanation and an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Anderson Vieira Ok, the code above shows how to sort 3 lists. What if i would add more array list to mylist. how could I change the code so it doesn't matter how many lists are in mylist.

Comment: @Anderson Vieira I am sorry the list is sorting dynamically I didn't realize it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @TimDaiber That's right, this will sort as many lists as there are stored in `mylist`. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

To sort by alphabetical order of the first item of each list, implement a custom Comparator:

```
    Collections.sort(mylist, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(ArrayList<String> arg0, ArrayList<String> arg1) {
            return arg0.get(0).compareTo(arg1.get(0));
        }

    });
```

You cannot reverse the order of this sort unless there is a particular algorithm you can use sort the element's original order. This being said, to maintain the original order just create a copy of the List and sort either the original (or copied), which will leave you with a sorted and unsorted copy of the List.

Comment: Sorry for the maybe dumb question. Is the above code in a separate method or class? I am just not quiet sure how I implement the code into mine.

Comment: Use this inside a method - this sorts the list inline. The sort method of Collections is a static method, and the Comparator is an anonymous class. After passing your List and Comparator to Collections.sort, the List will be sorted.